# How can I use a frequency counter to show the rpm of a spinning disc?

Tags: frequency

I don't want to unbalance the disc by attaching anything heavy to it. Is there a way of doing this optically?

Comment: Paint a white spot on the disk and reflect a light off the disk so you get a pulse every time the white spot passes your detector.

Comment: Google "optical tachometer".

Comment: Thanks John Rennie and Blue. Can I buy an optical detector at my local electronics store and would it need some circuitry to send a signal to the frequency counter?